# How to use `sprintf()` in LHS during assignment

Tags: r, evaluation

### Preamble

Just to illustrate the problem, let's say I am writing a function that returns `TRUE` if a column exists in the data frame and produces an error if it doesn't.

We can do this using `stopifnot()`:

```r
does_column_exist <- function(data, col_name) {
  stopifnot("column exists" = col_name %in% colnames(data))
  return(TRUE)
}

does_column_exist(mtcars, "mpg")
#> [1] TRUE
try(does_column_exist(mtcars, "mpg2"))
#> Error in does_column_exist(mtcars, "mpg2") : column exists
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### Problem

But note that the error message is vague. If I were to apply this function in a mapper, it'll be difficult to see which column doesn't exist.

To solve this, I can try to customize the name for the provided expression to contain the column name:

```r
does_column_exist2 <- function(data, col_name) {
  stopifnot(sprintf("%s column exists", col_name) = col_name %in% colnames(data))
  return(TRUE)
}
```

But this code isn't syntactically valid (`Error: unexpected '='`).

So I am wondering if there is any way to use `sprintf()` in LHS of an assignment? If not, how could one customize the name for expression in `stopifnot()` calls?

Comment: I’d argue that `stopifnot()` is simply the wrong solution here. Use a proper `if (…) stop("…message…")` — of course you can wrap that into a function at will.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Possibly so. But note that this was the most minimal example I could find to showcase what I am trying to do. Unfortunately, I am trying to stick to the specs I have received that expect `stopifnot()` and so, the best solution or not, I needed a way to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot evaluate something on the left hand side of `=` or `<-`. That's also the reason why people use `assign` or data.table makes use of the `:=` operator.

What you can do instead? Usually [`do.call`](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html#do-call) comes in handy in such situations. Here, since `stopifnot()` works with named arguments, `setNames()` is also an option:

```
does_column_exist2 <- function(data, col_name) {
  # setNames
  stopifnot(setNames(nm = sprintf("%s column exists", col_name),
                     object = col_name %in% colnames(data)))
  
  # do.call with setNames(). 
  # bit unessecary here but do.call works in many situations in which evaluated 
  # arguments should be used
  do.call(stopifnot, list(setNames(nm = sprintf("%s column exists", col_name), 
                                   object = col_name %in% colnames(data))))
  return(TRUE)
}
```

Comment: `do.call()` seems to do the trick! Thanks.